# Referencing generic object.__add__ in python 3

Tags: python

I'm writing a parser that is able to parse a string into an equation.

When I come across a symbol, say `+`, I need to produce a function that takes two inputs and adds them.

While I *could* simply write a lambda function to do it, it seems silly to write a function for such a purpose, and I'd end up with a map like:

```
map = {
    '+': lambda a,b: a+b,
    '-': lambda a,b: a-b,
    # More symbols here
}
```

Furthermore, the functions I'm looking for [are already defined in object](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__)!  This way, I can do something like:

```
map = {
    '+': object.__add__,
    '-': object.__sub__,
    # More symbols here
}
```

However, when I try the above code, I get a `type object 'object' has no attribute '__add__'` error.

How do I reference the functions that I need?

Comment: The documentation you're looking at is using `object` as a generic placeholder for the actual type you're dealing with, perhaps misleadingly. `object` doesn't actually implement most of those methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the operator module?

```
import operator
operators = {"+": operator.add}
```

Usage:

```
>>> operators["+"](10,10)
20
```

Comment: Ah, the operator module is what I'm looking for!  Do you know why I can't reference `object.__add__`, but other methods like `object.__lt__` work?

Comment: @NathanMerrill: `object.__add__` doesn't exist, and even if it did, it would refer specifically to `object`'s implementation of `__add__`. You want something that does what `+` does, including dynamic method lookup and `__radd__` handling, so you want `operator.add`. Incidentally, you also want `operator.lt` instead of `object.__lt__`.

Comment: @user2357112 ah, that makes sense.  Thank you!